# Thales HSM: relationship between the various key types?

Tags: key, hsm

I am going through the Thales HSM manuals, and frankly the key acronyms are driving me crazy. I would like to understand the differences between the following keys, and how they relate to one another:

- LMK
- TMK/TPK/TAK/TEK
- ZMK/ZPK/ZAK/ZEK
- DEK
- KEK

I know that in terms of "hierarchy" (if that's the right term to use), LMK > TMK/ZMK > TPK/ZPK...and that's it. Specifically, I would also like to know:

1. Which key should I use if I'm looking for general purpose encryption/decryption? How about key wrapping?
2. Can zone keys and terminal keys be used interchangeably (e.g TPK and ZPK)?

Answer (score 1):

LMK is Local Master Key which is the root key protecting all the other keys. This LMK is generated by 3 components and divided in to 3 smart cards. LMK is responsible for encrypting all the other keys. LMK is stored in plain in HSM secure area.

> 1. Which key should I use if I'm looking for general purpose encryption/decryption? How about key wrapping?

For this, you can use TPK which will be used for encryption and decryption.

The process will be as below:

1. Generate a TPK
2. Encrypt TPK from TMK, this will create TWK
3. TMK will be injected
4. TWK will be defined in code level or in a profile
5. When something needs to be encrypted, TWK will be decrypted with TMK to receive TPK, TPK will encrypt and vise versa

> 2. Can zone keys and terminal keys be used interchangeably (e.g TPK and ZPK)?

Zone keys are designed to exchange keys between HSMs.
You can wrap a TPK from ZPK and share.